# evento click carouselview xamarin

Tags: xamarin

Tenho 5 imagens e preciso ativar o carouselview para abrir uma página no momento em que o usuário clica, mas não está funcionando

Eu tentei fazer isso

```
MAinCarousel.ItemSelected += (sender, args) =>
        {
            this.Navigation.PushAsync(new MyPage(int.Parse(MAinCarousel.Position.ToString())));
            listView.SelectedItem = null;
        };
```

Desta forma, ele dispara no momento em que rolo o carrossel, eu quero o evento quando ele clica

Comment: Olá Jose, Esse é o StackOverflow em Português, teria como você traduzir sua pergunta? Caso queira pode postar também no [SOen](https://stackoverflow.com/). Aproveite e faça um [tour](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/tour) para saber qual a melhor forma de elaborar uma pergunta.

Comment: Traduzido, desculpa

Comment: Algum erro aparece no Output do Visual Studio? Alguma exception? Já tentou utilizar o método ItemTapped?